# Is it possible to create a new database in MongoDB with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to figure out if I can create a new database in MongoDB with Mongoose. I am running on Node, and I know the MongoDB driver for Node can do it, but I am wondering if I can do it just from Mongoose.

Is there an equivalent to the `db.createCollection(name, options)` from the Node MongoDB driver in Mongoose? My google skills are failing right now.

I just was trying to figure out if I had to install the whole MongoDB driver just for that, but I think I do.

Comment: What is your usecase for creating a new collection with mongoose? that's not something you would normally need to do with mongoose, other than the fact that mongoose will create a collection for a schema if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: I think I might have mixed up the terminology; I just want to create a database if it doesn't exist without having to install the whole driver just for that. I'm editing the question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the database name in your connection string.

```
db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbname1')
```

As soon as you create a record with that connection, it will create the new database and collections under the database name of 'dbname1'. If you wanted to create a new database, you can specify a different connection string:

```
db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbname2')
```

and that will create all your records under the name 'dbname2'. Your documents will not import over to dbname2, you will have to do an import of those records if you wanted to do that. Hope that helps.

Comment: This should still work, the Mongoose documentation is here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp'); You might be running into a different error

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create database for online cluster you also need to enter your database name when you pass the uri like:-

> `"mongodb+srv://<Username>:<Password>@resumeapp.3ditras.mongodb.net/<DatabaseName>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"`

Answer (score -3):

Just Try this code it's very simple and clean

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/yourdatabasename').then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB...')).catch((err) => console.error("Coudn't connect MongoDB....", err));

const customerSchema= new mongoose.Schema({ name: String,address: String,email:String,});

const Customer= mongoose.model('Customer',courseSchema);

async function createNewCustomer() {const customer= new Customer({name: 'new customer',address: 'new address',email: 'customer1@new.com',});const result = await customer.save();console.log(result);
}
createNewCustomer();
```